# Java Map to java object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I m having a map(which is formed from a Json ) as follows,

```
{office=null, basicFunc=Brokerage Documents, id=null, status=Good, rcvdDateTime=08/01/2013 01:48:25, orgUnit=5L9890327, numOfPg=null, ip=null, content=null, btchName=ONLINE UPLOAD, docTypeCde=20130801, rqstId=null, filNm={subrecord={subfiled1=[value1, value2]}}, docSizeBytes=null, docId=1234567, doctype=ConversionAgreement}
```

and having a POJO as below

```
public class IDocument {
    private String basicFunc;
    private String doctype;
    private String orgUnit;     
    @JsonDeserialize(as=Subrecord.class,contentAs=Subrecord.class)
    private Subrecord filNm;
    private String content;
```

}

```
public class Subrecord {    
    private List<Subfiled1> subField1;
    public List<Subfiled1> getSubField1() {
        return subField1;
    }
    public void setSubField(List<Subfiled1> subField1) {
        this.subField1 = subField1;
    }
}

public class Subfiled1 {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

i am converting the map into IDocument object using jackson as below,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
IDocument iDocObj = mapper.convertValue(map, IDocument.class);
```

In iDocObj iam able to get values for everything except filnm,it is coming as null

iDocObj.getFilNm().getSubField1() = null;

**How to ge values for getFilNm.**

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON it is named subfiled1 and in java it is subfield ... so check the right naming convention

Comment: then this is recognized as List<String> in Subrecord your JSON is wrong you should have `subfiled1={value1: "Somevalue", value2:"Somevalue2"}`